# Copying ComboBox Items to a StringCollection in C#

Tags: c#, combobox, copy, items, stringcollection

How can I copy a collection of items in a `comboBox` to a `StringCollection` in my C# application?  I'm only interested in capturing the string text for each item in their respective order.  I am trying to make a MRU file list that is saved between sessions, so I would like to copy `comboBox.Items` to `StringCollection Properties.Settings.Default.MostRecentlyUsedHexFiles`.  Any thoughts or suggestions you may have would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to loop over the combobox.items and simply use stringcollection.Add() to add the string to the collection.

The tostring method will perform as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.items.aspx):

> Although the ComboBox is typically
>   used to display text items, you can
>   add any object to the ComboBox.
>   Typically, the representation of an
>   object in the ComboBox is the string
>   returned by that object's ToString
>   method. If you want to have a member
>   of the object displayed instead,
>   choose the member that will be
>   displayed by setting the DisplayMember
>   property to the name of the
>   appropriate member. You can also
>   choose a member of the object that
>   will represent the value returned by
>   the object by setting the ValueMember
>   property. For more information, see
>   ListControl.

So something like:

```
Foreach(object o in combobox.items)
{
//might need to access a datamember of the combobox's item if more complex solution is required, but this will probably do
stringcollection.Add(o.ToString);
}
```